# Cloudant Search feature in CouchDB Local server

Tags: lucene, couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-lucene

I have a search index like so in Cloudant:

```
"indexes": {
    "search-cloud": {
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "index": "function(doc) { index(\"keyword\", doc.name); }"
    }
}
```

The function is a bit more intense but that is the set up.

It appears its using this? `org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic`

Right now I have a local Fauxton CouchDB 1.6.1 database that I'm staging the data on but it appears that the search isn't implemented on it.

Is there a way to install this so I can make the following call to the database and get info back?

```
http://localhost/{DB}/_design/filters/_search/search-cloud?q={SEARCH_QUERY}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search stack behind IBM Cloudant is powered by Apache Lucene and was open sourced awhile back. I think this article on [enabling full text search in Apache CouchDB](https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2015/text-search-apache-couchdb/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Bradley. I actually ended up getting the [Cloudant Developer Edition](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/cloudant-developer/) which worked fine but will most definitely make note of this article!

Comment: Oh yes—I should have mentioned the Cloudant Developer Edition as well. Glad to hear you got it working.